# No transit visa in London when traveling from Canada - still valid during COVID?

Tags: canada, transit-visas, london, covid-19, quarantine

I and my husband will be traveling from Canada to Russia and back through London Heathrow (long layovers both ways). We have Canadian study and work permits and we are Russian citizens. Normally, with a Canadian permit, we would be able to leave the airport without a transit visa and go to London if we have a second leg of the flight within 24 hours. Does this rule still apply during COVID times or was it changed?

Answer (score 3):

TWOV is still applicable to your circumstances. However, if you enter the UK you will need to follow the rules on quarantine. Neither Canada nor Russia are currently on the list of exempt countries. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-how-to-self-isolate-when-you-travel-to-the-uk/coronavirus-covid-19-how-to-self-isolate-when-you-travel-to-the-uk

Comment: In practice, if no overnight stay is involved, there's not much to do to enforce the UK quarantine regulations (not that it's done either way; I'm from a non-exempt country and have been there 3 times since the restriction was introduced)

Comment: @Crazydre What do you mean "not much to do to enforce the UK quarantine regulations"? They can simply not let me leave airport.

Comment: @lastfreespot There's no rule for that, so it'd be decided on a case-by-case basis. You could call the Border Force if you want (I can give you the number if you say what terminal you'll land at - it's the flight TO London that counts)

Comment: @Crazydre can you please give me the contact to terminal 5? I am travelling next week and want to know how does covid affect TWOV.

Comment: @BhushanKale +44 20 8196 2490. COVID doesn't affect TWOV, except that you need to register online https://www.gov.uk/provide-journey-contact-details-before-travel-uk